# How to send messages from an app to a user using restfb?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use restfb to send a message to who likes the page.Using the graph API I got the page access_token and recipient_id.When I try to send it ends in an exception showing

**Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired on Friday, 03-Feb-17 03:00:00 PST. The current time is Friday, 03-Feb-17 21:20:41 PST. (code 190, subcode 463)**

But when I try to access the details of user in graph it is working fine.Am i doing something wrong?..Please help
Thanks in advance....

The java code

```
import java.util.List;

import com.restfb.*;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient.AccessToken;
import com.restfb.exception.FacebookException;
import com.restfb.json.JsonObject;
import com.restfb.types.Conversation;
import com.restfb.types.Message;
import com.restfb.types.User;
import com.restfb.types.send.IdMessageRecipient;
import com.restfb.types.send.PhoneMessageRecipient;
import com.restfb.types.send.SendResponse;

import facebook4j.Facebook;

public class Fbsample {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws FacebookException
{
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("***");
    User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
    String name=user.getFirstName();
    String email=user.getEmail();
    String id=user.getId();
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(id);
    JsonObject picture =    facebookClient.fetchObject("me/picture",JsonObject.class,Parameter.with("redirect","false"), Parameter.with("type","large"));
    System.out.println(picture);
    IdMessageRecipient recipient = new IdMessageRecipient("****");
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setMessage("Hello");

    String pageAccessToken ="***";

 // create a version 2.6 client
 FacebookClient pageClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken, Version.VERSION_2_6);

 SendResponse resp = pageClient.publish("me/messages", SendResponse.class,
      Parameter.with("recipient", recipient), // the id or phone recipient
     Parameter.with("message", msg)); // one of the messages from above
 }
 }
```

Here instead of real access token and recipient_id I have given * for now.And one more thing which id should I give the user_id or conversation_id and access token for page or user?...

Comment: did you try with a page token? use the page id, not /me

Comment: You can not message people just because they liked your page.